# How do I list the tags for a runner using python-gitlab

Tags: python-gitlab

I know how to get to (some) attributes of runners setup for a gitlab project. I need though to list the tags each runner defines?

Below is as far as I have gone.

```
gl = gitlab.Gitlab(url=<my-gitlab-url>, private_token=<my-gitlab-api-token>)

project = gl.projects.get(<my-project-id>)

for runner in project.runners.list(get_all=True):
    # How do I list the tags for the runner?
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it: Adding `runner = gl.runners.get(runner.id)` fills in many more attributes of the runner.

```
gl = gitlab.Gitlab(url=<my-gitlab-url>, private_token=<my-gitlab-api-token>)

project = gl.projects.get(<my-project-id>)

for runner in project.runners.list(get_all=True):
    runner = gl.runners.get(runner.id)
    print(runner.tag_list)
```